# Free introductory resources for learning algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, education, learning

I have a non-mathematician friend who is interested in re-learning algebra. I am more than happy to help, but I am in no position to judge what is a **good** introductory text --- only to identify when a text is a very **bad** one.

My friend is interested in starting from "basics" --- he's comfortable with order-of-operations, minus-times-minus-is-plus, and positive integer exponents. He's shaky with negative exponents, logarithms, and roots.

Any recommendations for good, freely-available resources?

Comment: people love to recommend http://www.khanacademy.org/, but I have no experience with it.

Comment: I assume you mean the version that isn't called "abstract algebra" and is about groups and such (Lang's book is about that)

For self-study I'd suggest you take a look at the Schaum's series about algebra, they are cheap, full of examples and exercises.

Comment: I don't understand, I always thought Lang is a great book - that is what I used myself.

Comment: @muad: The question was about highschool algebra.

Comment: Oops! I was thinking of *Algebra* By Saunders Mac Lane, Garrett Birkhoff. Don't know why I confused that with Lang!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/) offers dozens of videos on particular Algebra topics, among thousands of videos on other academic topics.

Answer (score 1):

[Curriki](http://www.curriki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome) is supposed to be a good resource for this kind of stuff, but I haven't tried it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty good video course on YouTube EDU, ["College Algebra"](http://www.youtube.com/user/UMKC#grid/user/DE28CF08BD313B2A)