# Which books for refreshing high school algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'll take a Calculus course next year, and my professor suggested reviewing high school algebra.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free introductory resources for learning algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/free-introductory-resources-for-learning-algebra)

Answer (score 14):

This [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817636773), by Israel Gelfand, is perhaps the best book on high school algebra I have ever seen. Written by a leading mathematician, it is short, clear, and concise, yet provides a depth of understanding that you cannot find in many other books on the subject.

Comment: Gelfand was a giant. Definitely have a look at this!!!

Answer (score 7):

- $\text{Higher Algebra}$ by $\text{Hall and Knight}$ is also a good book and has good deal of high school algebra.
- You might also want to look at S.L.Loney's $\text{ Plane Trigonometry}$. Since you are going to learn $\text{Calculus}$ it might be important that you know some Trigonometry.

Answer (score 4):

See also Lang's *[Basic Mathematics](http://books.google.com/books?id=gBtvo480ng4C)*.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to take a look at the text by George F. Simmons, [Precalculus Mathematics in a Nutshell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592441300). It is very concise, weighing in at only 128 pages, and like other books by Simmons, is extremely clear and well-written.