# What is a good book to learn about pre algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request

I only found one book i liked , i like to share it here .
[Algebra](https://hillcrestmath.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/8th-grade-algebra-i-textbook.pdf)

Can someone recommend any other books ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078059/pre-algebra-book-recommendation?rq=1

Comment: Thanks , i am looking for a book that contains lot of examples for rational and radical expressions and equations , The one i posted is the only one that has examples like that .  Does anyone know  any books with example and worked out problems of rational and radical expressions and equations ?

Comment: Also see https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/rational-expressions-equations-and-functions and try Project Gutenberg. https://people.ucsc.edu/~miglior/chapter%20pdf/Ch06_SE.pdf, https://2012books.lardbucket.org/pdfs/beginning-algebra/s11-radical-expressions-and-equati.pdf, https://www.saddleback.edu/faculty/lperez/algebra2go/cahsee/equations/35.pdf,

Comment: Thanks a lot Moo . That would be enough for the studies :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looking for a good precalculus/algebra reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44240/looking-for-a-good-precalculus-algebra-reference)

Comment: Duplicates https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1396876.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying the most basic algebra. Then I would suggest this.

[Introduction to Algebra](https://artofproblemsolving.com/store/item/intro-algebra)