# What is a good book for reviewing high school math, and preparing for university?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, self-learning, book-recommendation

I'm signing up for University soon (Compsci program) as a mature student. It's been a long time since I've done any math, and I went as far as grade 11 in high school. So, I'm looking for a book that will review the essentials of high school math, starting from the basics, and prepare me for Uni.

Any recommendations? I know many of you recommended "Mathematics: Its Content, Methods and Meaning" in the past, but I'm not sure if it's beginner-friendly. Perhaps I should buy one of those GED preparation books?

Comment: there is one such book?

Comment: related to:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23740/good-book-for-high-school-algebra?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Introduction to mathematical thinking-Keith Devlin (Stanford professor)

Comment: I think it may be to advanced for me, It looks like it's aimed for grade 12 to 1st and 2nd year college/uni students. I need a book that will go through the fundamentals of high school math, from grade 9 to 12.

"The book is written primarily for first and second year students of science, technology, engineering, and mathematics (STEM) at colleges and universities, and for high school students intending to study a STEM subject at university"

Answer (score 1):

One book that's really great is Serge Lang - Basic Mathematics. It's an algebra/trig book that is written like you're intelligent. It's written in the same style as more serious books.