# best books for learning algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education

My name is Aniket and I have started 11th class recently. I have studied only my school textbooks([NCERT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Council_of_Educational_Research_and_Training) Books) and I am not happy with them.

I want to learn Algebra,i.e, all the topics covered in algebra 1 and 2.
I want to learn algebra enough to master up to 12th class, but I am very confused which is the best book to achieve all of my goals.

Book Price = less than $17 (American Dollars)
And I don't want an eBook.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: artofproblemsolving.com sells various books in Algebra that I believe would be suited to your level. e.g. https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Store/viewitem.php?item=intro:algebra

Comment: is there any book whose price is less than $17.....

Comment: American dollars? Canadian dollars? Australian dollars? New Zealand dollars?

Comment: American Dollar.And I don't want any ebook.

Comment: The majority of books used here in the United States are both expensive and not very good for self teaching. [Here are some free eBooks](http://www.ck12.org/algebra/), which I know aren't what your looking for, but they might help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free introductory resources for learning algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/free-introductory-resources-for-learning-algebra)

Answer (score 3):

if you are an Indian, please note that all major book publishers provide very cheap books in Indian subcontinent. For example, Higher Algebra by Hall & Knight is priced USD20.91 on Amazon.com for Paperback which you can buy for a negligible ₹100 (~USD 1.70) at Indian stores. And this is the only book I can suggest you for Algebra. I have collected some other [algebra books](http://gauravtiwari.org/2011/05/02/free-online-algebra-books/) on my site, if you are further interested.

Answer (score 1):

[Solutions of the Examples in Higher Algebra (LaTeX Edition)](http://www.flipkart.com/solutions-examples-higher-algebra-latex-edition-english/p/itme6krr9pfvv3ap?pid=9781508763505) by Hall and Knight is available at Flipkart

It is also available at [amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/150876350X)

Comment: http://www.amazon.in/dp/150876350X

Answer (score 0):

just google for *algebra, lecture notes, filetype:pdf* or something like that

http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/bobh/UoS/rfwhole.pdf

Comment: Mate, that's Abstract Algebra, not high school algebra.

Comment: yes.....i don't want abstract algebra.
So,Please suggest some books and their authors that are to the level of high school...

Comment: Thanks for the textbook on abstract algebra, though. :)