# Suggest book(s) for Algebra I, Algebra II, Geometry and Trigonometry that goes in great details and explains all sides of the problems

Tags: education, book-recommendation

I am currently reading for Dummies series of those math books and they are quite good as introduction and I really like them. But I have feeling that there can be much more extensive coverage of topics, more details and much more ways of doing same things. Can you please suggest book(s) that cover all (or nearly all) sides in great details for for Algebra I, Algebra II, Geometry and Trigonometry?

Comment: Look for the series of notes by [William Chen](https://williamchen-mathematics.info/). Well written, cover most of the first/second year college math curriculum (and some other stuff). Look for the [Open math notes by AMS](https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes). There are lots of further resources, including videos. Take a peek and select what *you* like best.

Comment: You can always count on Serge Lang to be extensive.  You have to be pretty good to read his stuff but here's the link:  https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387220253

Comment: Does this answer your question? [best books for learning algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701334/best-books-for-learning-algebra)

Comment: @Abdallahchaibeddrraa No. My book is not only for algebra and I do not have restriction on price.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this book of schaum https://b-ok.cc/book/439658/4502c4