# Books with huge collections of hard, and original, problems on High School & Olympiad-level l Algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm searching for great and unknown books with huge collections of hard and original problems for my students on High School Algebra or Olympiad level Algebra,  related (**but not limited**) to factoring polynomials and identities.

What I need is a huge collection of **hard and unseen** **problems** in high school algebra, because unfortunately most of the problems in these books below are well-known to my students and ***cannot feed their hunger***. My students are about 13 and 14, are really talented.

- *Problem Solving Strategies* by Arthur Engel
- *101 Problems in Algebra* by Titu Andreescu and Zuming Feng
- *Introduction to Algebra* by Richard Rusczyk

Comment: Over the past 15 years I've posted many such things in usenet and at Math Forum, and more recently at stackexchange. I don't have a full collection of these posts, but some that I could think of now are [Some turbo-charged high school algebra](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6344054) (21 August 2008 sci.math post), [minimizing quadratic/quadratic without calculus](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6528441), and my answer to [Is number rational?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778661/is-number-rational).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free introductory resources for learning algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/free-introductory-resources-for-learning-algebra)

Answer (score 2):

[***Challenging Problems in Algebra*** (Dover) by Alfred S. Posamentier and Charles T. Salkind (Dover)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486691489) would certainly fit your needs.

If not, then you can look at [***Problem-Solving Strategies***](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/book/978-0-387-98219-9) by Engel. It has a section on polynomials which contains 82 problems.

Another option is [**101 Problems in Algebra From the Training of the USA IMO Team**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/187642012X) by Titu Andreescu, Zuming Feng. You could also take a look at the [**IMO Compendium**](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/book/978-1-4419-9853-8). It contains some interesting algebra problems.

Comment: I've seen this book I mean something different. sth like olympiad or pre-olympiad level algebra problems

Comment: @mmahdit I suggested two other books in my recent edit.

Comment: thanks for both books I meant sth stranger because most of my students have read the second one. Engel's book is in hands of most of them and I myself enjoyed reading it years ago when I was student. Thanks again for your kind help :)

Comment: @mmahdit What about the third one?

Comment: the 3rd one is a great book and I've read it when I was student. I mean sth like problems of the first chapter of this book.

Comment: I'm collecting unseen and new problems...

Comment: @mmahdit What about the fourth book I suggested?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check it soon.

Comment: @mmahdit You're welcome, very happy to help! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find [*Polynomials* by E.J. Barbeau](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387406271) to satisfy your request very nicely indeed. It's probably the most exhaustive source on this topic for beginners and contains an enormous wealth of exercises. It's also extremely clear and gives many insights into the theory of polynomials at this level,mostly without abstract algebra.More sophisticated aspects of polynomials which require basic ring and field theory are discussed in optional sections.

I think you'll find this book just what the doctor ordered.

Comment: op's students might have seen it and may be aware of it.

Comment: ok,but didn't see anything that indicated that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Art of Problem Solving's](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/index.php?) community? You can either search for "polynomial" and cherry pick the problems you like, or just go to the olympiad section for algebra. You'll find all levels there.

Comment: It's been years that I'm checking that website but it takes along time to cherry pick those problems.you asked about their age: they are about 13-14 and they are highly talented. some of them are really gifted and sometimes I find a genius among them. So I'm deeply responsible to those talents.

Answer (score 0):

One resource that I use from time to time is Leonhard Euler's *Elements of Algebra*. There aren't a lot of practice problems, but some of the ones that he does have are somewhat difficult.
As an example, take a look at problem 12 on this page. https://archive.org/stream/elementsalgebra00lagrgoog#page/n277/mode/2up