# Book recommendations for highschool algebra for concepts and hard problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am looking for a **book recommendations for learning algebra for high school**.

Usually my exams(national level competitions) may even ask some of the things that are a bit beyond the syllabus, and have really hard problems. So I want a book that goes over both theory in some detail and also contains hard problems and maybe a few tricks.

I am looking for a book in algebra that goes over topics like:

[This is the prescribed syllabus]

> **Algebra**
>
> Algebra  of  **complex  numbers**,  addition,  multiplication,  conjugation,  polar  representation, properties  of  modulus  and  principal  argument,  triangle  inequality,  cube  roots  of  unity, geometric interpretations.
>
> **Quadratic  equations**  with  real  coefficients,  relations  between  roots  and  coefficients, formation  of quadratic equations  with  given  roots,  symmetric functions  of roots.
>
> Arithmetic,  geometric  and  harmonic  **progressions**,  arithmetic,  geometric    and  harmonic means,  sums  of  finite  arithmetic  and  geometric  progressions,  infinite  geometric  series, sums  of squares  and  cubes  of the first n natural numbers.
>
> **Logarithms**  and  their  properties.
>
> **Permutations  and  combinations**, **binomial  theorem**  for  a  positive  integral  index, properties  of  binomial  coefficients

Please can someone help me ?? :)

Thank You

Comment: There are good resources listed here https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-resources-for-preparing-for-the-IMO

Comment: @VatsalLimbachia I'm looking for books that are difficult , but not specifically for imo. Eg I believe complex numbers are not used much here ( correct me if I I'm worng, because I'm not really sure.

Comment: @VatsalLimbachia I have edited the question, so that it becomes more clear now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free introductory resources for learning algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/free-introductory-resources-for-learning-algebra)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists the relics from the past which go from the very beginning to such topics as complex numbers in deep. 
$$.$$
G Chrystal, an elementary texbook volume 1 and 2.$$.$$
Hall and Knight, elementary algebra volume 1 and 2. (though it's also named as "elementary algeba for schools")
$$.$$
For an advanced standpoint, you can read B.D Bunday and H. Mulholland "Pure mathematics for advanced level", though in my opinion you should read Chrystal's algebra 
 first for it is one of those books that never age and deals with many interesting topics (even series, interesting identities and so on) so you should do fine just with it, since the book is kinda old you can find it online.

Comment: Sorry to say but these books are not that good and even lack advanced theory. Eg in G Chrystal , the complex number don't go over Euler form and the geometric discussion is too brief.

Comment: Refer to Titu Andrescu's books for challenging problems in different fields plus Hungarian problem books.

Comment: This link refers to many books for every subject which I have found most helpful. 
https://imomath.com/index.php?options=347&lmm=0

Comment: Sk mapa, Barnard child higher algebra,titu andresscu. Try sk mapa first really great book . Both the books mentioned are more tough than hall and knight